# create new objects from list only if its not in django database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I am having a list of python objects.

suppose `py_objs_list = [...data...]`
Model is `Card`

I want to create a new object in django database only if database already dont have object

My solution is to do `objects.all()` on my `Card` and run a for loop on `py_objs_list` and check if `py_obj` in `objects.all()`.
If not present im taking that `py_obj` into seperate list.
Finally creating objects using `bulk_create`

```
py_objs_list = [...data...]
cards = list(Card.objects.al()) <--- i know db hits here --->

emails = [card.email for card in cards] <--- does db hit here also everytime in a loop --->
empty_list = []

for py_obj in py_objs_list:
    if py_obj[some_data] not in emails:
        empty_list.append(py_obj)

---bulk_create---
```

Is this the best way to tackle this problem? pls tell me if not (want the best one). thnks:)

Now my doubt is does db hit everytime in list comprehension as mentioned above

[my solution for this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRShQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bulk_create` and set `ignore_conflicts=True`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

This will just ignore any records in the object list that cannot be created becuase they already exist.

Comment: thnks, but i also want to show validation errors and already existing objects errors

Answer (score 0):

I think using [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) would be better for your scenario.

Just run a loop over your original list and use as many fields as you want to make sure that a unique instance is found, like so

```
py_obj_list = [...data...]

for py_obj in py_obj_list:
        Card.objects.get_or_create(email=py_obj.email)
```

Comment: I would say that is doing a lot of unnecessary db reads, since they don't actually want info on the pre-existing records.

Comment: But it will hit the database multiple times, which i think isnt optimized code.

Comment: The db reads may be necessary because you actually need to see if the record exists in the db before doing anything else. As for hitting the database multiple times, I think that within one iteration, it both checks and creates(which may not always be the case since the record may exist in the db), this is definitely better than running two separate loops with if checks within them.